# Copy list item attachments to a document library in SharePoint 2013 designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, designer-workflow

Is it possible to copy the attachments of a list item to a Document library using 2013 designer workflows?

I am able to get the server relative URL of the attachments in the workflow, but I am not sure if there is a way to copy using the server relative URL

[image]

Is there a method like [copyto](http://johnliu.net/blog/2014/2/19/using-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-to-copy-file-via-res.html) that exists for copying files from library to a different library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the below request as a http request and called it from Designer workflow and it is copying files as expected

```
$.ajax({
url:"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/sitename/Lists/ListName/Attachments/11/sample.jpg')/copyTo(strNewUrl='DestinationRelativeURL',bOverWrite=true)",
headers:{"accept":"application/json;odata=verbose","content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose","X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()},
method: "POST",
success:function(data){
console.log(data);
},
error:function(xhr){
console.log(xhr);
}
})
```

Before making this http request, we need to make one http request`(_api/contextinfo)` to get the RequestDigest